# Как сделать Collections.sort без тернарного оператора if

Tags: java, сортировка, коллекции, map

В коде для сортировки папки `Map<String, Integer >`воспользовался с `Collections.sort`. Код работает, сортирует и по ключам и по значениям. Но меня заинтересовало как можно сделать эту же сортировку без тернарного оператора? Возможно ли это?

```
Collections.sort(list2, (o1, o2) -> o1.getValue()-o2.getValue() != 0 
    ?  o1.getValue()-o2.getValue() 
    :  o2.getKey().compareTo(o1.getKey())
);
```

Comment: читайте про Comparator и Comparable

Comment: Это вроде тоже самое, тоже использует if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использование разности при сравнении целых чисел не рекомендуется, чтобы избежать ошибок при переполнении, если например в значениях или ключах будут `Integer.MIN_VALUE` и `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

А так, для исключения тернарного оператора здесь напрашивается цепочка компараторов:

```
Collections.sort(list2, Map.Entry.<Integer, Integer>comparingByValue()
    .thenComparing(Map.Entry::getKey, Comparator.reverseOrder())
);
```

Кроме того, начиная с Java 8, `List` имеет метод [`List::sort(Comparator<? super E> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)) для сортировки самого себя:

```
list2.sort(Map.Entry.<Integer, Integer>comparingByValue()
    .thenComparing(Map.Entry::getKey, Comparator.reverseOrder())
);
```

Comment: Откуда так хорошо знаешь методы.... сразу так трудно определить как что надо

Comment: Нужно много работать с ними чтоб так легко маневрировать